# Inquire about the retrieval of the firebase DB works

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Let's imagine "posts" contains 5000 posts inside it. When I retrieve data from my Database on Firebase on RecyclerView with the condition `orderByChild`, has all the data (the 5000 posts) been called or just a fraction (like 15 posts)? For instance, when I scroll down does it call another 15 posts?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a listener for 5000 items, and the database contains at least 5000 items, then your listener callback will be invoked with a snapshot of those 5000 items.

If you want to load a subset of the items to implement pagination in your UI, you will have to implement this yourself. I highly recommend doing a few searches for previous questions (and other material) on [Firebase pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+pagination) in that case.